Loss and Accuracy not improving while fine-tuning a pre-trained Vision Transformer (ViT) model
I have been trying to train a pre-trained ViT Model for my case specific task. But even after some epochs, the losses didnt come down.
Epoch 0:

Loss: 3.0653
Accuracy: 0.1276
Val Loss: 2.3186
Val Accuracy: 0.1297

Epoch 1:

Loss: 3.0652
Accuracy: 0.1264
Val Loss: 2.3216
Val Accuracy: 0.1302

This pattern continues.
Here's my model:

    @staticmethod
    def _prepare_full_model(model, 
                            classes:int, 
                            freeze_all:bool, 
                            freeze_till:int, 
                            learning_rate:float, 
                            dropout_rate: float, 
                            l2_weight_decay: float):
        # Freeze all layers if freeze_all is true
        if freeze_all:
            for param in model.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False
        elif freeze_till is not None and freeze_till>0:
            #Freeze layers till freeze_till
            for idx, block in enumerate(model.encoder.layers):
                if idx<freeze_till:
                    for param in block.parameters():
                        param.requires_grad = False
                else:
                    for param in block.parameters():
                        param.requires_grad = True

        # Replace the classification head

        model.heads = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(768, 1024),
                                    nn.LeakyReLU(),
                                    nn.Dropout(dropout_rate),
                                    nn.Linear(1024, classes))

        print(summary(model = model, 
                input_size = (32,3,224,224), 
                col_names=["input_size", "output_size", "num_params", "trainable"],
                col_width = 20, row_settings = ["var_names"]))

        
        return model
    
    def update_base_model(self):
        self.full_model = self._prepare_full_model(model = self.model, 
                                                   classes = self.config.classes,
                                                   freeze_all = self.config.freeze_all, 
                                                   freeze_till = self.config.freeze_till, 
                                                   learning_rate = self.config.learning_rate, 
                                                   dropout_rate = self.config.dropout_rate, 
                                                   l2_weight_decay = self.config.l2_weight_decay
                                                   )
        self.save_model(self.config.updated_base_model_path, self.full_model)


The freeze_till parameter is set to 10. But changing the values of the parameter also didn't help.
This is how my model looks.




Layer (type (var_name))
Input Shape
Output Shape
Param #
Trainable




VisionTransformer (VisionTransformer)
[32, 3, 224, 224]
[32, 10]
768
Partial


├─Conv2d (conv_proj)
[32, 3, 224, 224]
[32, 768, 14, 14]
590,592
True


├─Encoder (encoder)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
151,296
Partial


│    └─Dropout (dropout)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
--
--


│    └─Sequential (layers)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
--
Partial


│    │    └─EncoderBlock (encoder_layer_0)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
7,087,872
False


│    │    └─EncoderBlock (encoder_layer_1)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
7,087,872
False


│    │    └─EncoderBlock (encoder_layer_2)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
7,087,872
False


│    │    └─EncoderBlock (encoder_layer_3)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
7,087,872
False


│    │    └─EncoderBlock (encoder_layer_4)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
7,087,872
False


│    │    └─EncoderBlock (encoder_layer_5)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
7,087,872
False


│    │    └─EncoderBlock (encoder_layer_6)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
7,087,872
False


│    │    └─EncoderBlock (encoder_layer_7)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
7,087,872
False


│    │    └─EncoderBlock (encoder_layer_8)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
7,087,872
False


│    │    └─EncoderBlock (encoder_layer_9)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
7,087,872
False


│    │    └─EncoderBlock (encoder_layer_10)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
7,087,872
True


│    │    └─EncoderBlock (encoder_layer_11)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
7,087,872
True


│    └─LayerNorm (ln)
[32, 197, 768]
[32, 197, 768]
1,536
True


├─Sequential (heads)
[32, 768]
[32, 10]
--
True


│    └─Linear (0)
[32, 768]
[32, 1024]
787,456
True


│    └─LeakyReLU (1)
[32, 1024]
[32, 1024]
--
--


│    └─Dropout (2)
[32, 1024]
[32, 1024]
--
--


│    └─Linear (3)
[32, 1024]
[32, 10]
10,250
True



| Total params: 86,596,362                                                                                                                    |
| Trainable params: 15,717,642                                                                                                                |
| Non-trainable params: 70,878,720                                                                                                            |
| Total mult-adds (G): 5.54                                                                                                                   |
| Input size (MB): 19.27                                                                                                                      |
| Forward/backward pass size (MB): 3331.00                                                                                                    |
| Params size (MB): 232.38                                                                                                                    |
| Estimated Total Size (MB): 3582.65                                                                                                          |

Code for Model Training

import torch
import torch.utils
from torchvision import datasets, models, transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, random_split
import json
import os
from paddydoctor.constants import *
from paddydoctor.logging import logger


class ModelTraining:
    def __init__(self, 
                 modeltrainingconfig: ModelTrainerConfig, 
                 datatransformconfig: DataTransformsConfig):
        
        self.modeltrainingconfig = modeltrainingconfig
        self.datatransformconfig = DataTransformsConfig
        self.device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
        self.config = modeltrainingconfig
        self.data_transforms = datatransformconfig
        self.model = self.load_model()
        self.model.to(self.device)

    def load_model(self):
        # model = models.vit_b_16()
        # model.load_state_dict(torch.load(self.config.updated_model_path))
        return torch.load(self.modeltrainingconfig.updated_model_path)
    def get_data_loaders(self):
        train_transforms = self._get_transforms_(self.data_transforms.train_transforms)
        # test_transforms = self._get_transforms_(self.data_transforms.test_transforms)

        train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root = self.config.train_dir, transform = train_transforms)
        # test_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root = self.config.test_dir, transform = test_transforms)

        # Define the split ratio for train and validation
        val_split = 0.2
        train_size = int((1-val_split) * len(train_dataset))
        val_size = len(train_dataset) - train_size

        # Split into train, valid subsets
        train_subset, val_subset = random_split(train_dataset, [train_size, val_size])

        self.train_loader = DataLoader(dataset = train_subset, 
                                       batch_size = self.config.params_batch_size, 
                                       shuffle = True)
        self.val_loader = DataLoader(dataset = val_subset, 
                                     batch_size = self.config.params_batch_size, 
                                     shuffle = True)
        # self.test_loader = DataLoader(dataset = test_dataset,
        #                               batch_size = self.config.params_batch_size, 
        #                               shuffle = False)
        
    def _get_transforms_(self, augmentations):
        transforms_list = []
        for aug in augmentations:
            if aug.name == "Resize":
                size = aug.params.get("size")
                transforms_list.append(transforms.Resize(tuple(size)))
            if aug.name == "ColorJitter":
                params = aug.params.to_dict()
                transforms_list.append(transforms.ColorJitter(**params))
            if aug.name == "ToTensor":
                transforms_list.append(transforms.ToTensor())
            if aug.name == "Normalize":
                params = aug.params.to_dict()
                transforms_list.append(transforms.Normalize(**params))
            if aug.name == "RandomHorizontalFlip":
                params = aug.params.to_dict()
                transforms_list.append(transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(**params))
            if aug.name=="RandomRotation":
                params = aug.params.to_dict()
                transforms_list.append(transforms.RandomRotation(**params))
        return transforms.Compose(transforms_list)
    
    
    def l1_regularization(self, model, l1_lambda):
        l1_norm = 0
        for param in model.parameters():
            if param.requires_grad and param.ndim>1:# only consider weights, not bias terms
                l1_norm+=param.abs().sum()
        return l1_lambda * l1_norm
    
    def train_one_epoch(self, epoch, model, optimizer, criterion, l1_lambda):
        model.train()
        running_loss = 0.0
        correct_predictions = 0
        total_samples = 0

        for inputs, label in self.train_loader:
            inputs, label = inputs.to(self.device), label.to(self.device)

            # Zero the parameters gradient
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # Forward Pass                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, label)


            # Add L1 regularization
            l1_loss = self.l1_regularization(model, l1_lambda)

            total_loss = l1_loss + loss
            running_loss += total_loss.item()

            # print("Loss: ",loss.item(),
            #       "l1_loss: ",l1_loss.item(), 
            #       "total_loss: ",total_loss.item(), 
            #       "running_loss: ", running_loss,"\n")

            # Zero the parameters gradient
            #optimizer.zero_grad()

            #Print gradient before backprop

            # pre_backward_grads = {}
            # for name, param in model.named_parameters():
            #     pre_backward_grads[name] = param.grad.clone() if param.grad is not None else None


            # Backprop
            total_loss.backward()

            for name, param in model.named_parameters():
                post_backward_grad = param.grad.clone() if param.grad is not None else None
            

            # Check if the gradients before and after are the same
            # if pre_backward_grads[name] is not None and post_backward_grad is not None:
            #     are_same = torch.equal(pre_backward_grads[name], post_backward_grad)
            #     print(f"Gradients for {name} are the same: {are_same}\n")
            

            #Optimizer step
            optimizer.step()



            
            #calculate accuracy
            predicted = torch.argmax(torch.softmax(outputs, dim=1), dim=1)# Get the index of the max log-probability
            correct_predictions+= (predicted==label).sum().item() #count correct predictions
            total_samples+= label.size(0) #count total samples in a batch
            

        epoch_loss = running_loss/len(self.train_loader)
        accuracy = correct_predictions/total_samples
        logger.info(f"Epoch {epoch} | Loss: {epoch_loss: .4f} | Accuracy: {accuracy: .4f}")
        return epoch_loss, accuracy
    
    def validate(self, epoch, model, criterion):
        model.eval()
        running_val_loss = 0.0
        correct_predictions = 0
        total_samples = 0
        with torch.no_grad():
            for inputs, label in self.val_loader:
                inputs, label = inputs.to(self.device), label.to(self.device)
                outputs = model(inputs)
                loss = criterion(outputs, label)
                running_val_loss+=loss.item()

                #calculate accuracy
                # _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                predicted = torch.argmax(torch.softmax(outputs, dim=1), dim=1)
                correct_predictions+=(predicted==label).sum().item()
                total_samples+= label.size(0)

                
        epoch_val_loss = running_val_loss/len(self.val_loader)
        acc_validation = correct_predictions/total_samples
        logger.info(f"Epoch {epoch} | Val Loss: {epoch_val_loss: .4f} | Val_Accuracy: {acc_validation:.4f}\n")
        return epoch_val_loss, acc_validation


    def train(self, callbacks, optimizer):
        with open(self.config.class_weight, "r") as f:
            class_weights = json.load(f)
        if isinstance(class_weights, dict):
            class_weights = list(class_weights.values())
        
        # Convert class_weights to tensor
        class_weights = torch.tensor(class_weights).to(device = self.device)
        criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight = class_weights)

        scheduler = callbacks["lr_scheduler"]
        early_stopping = callbacks["early_stopping"]
        # tensorboard = callbacks["tensorboard"]
        model_ckpt = callbacks["model_ckpt"]
        best_loss = float("inf")

        train_stats = {"train_loss": [], "train_acc": []}
        val_stats = {"val_loss": [], "val_acc": []}

        for epoch in range(self.config.params_num_epochs):
            # Train one epoch
            train_loss, train_accuracy = self.train_one_epoch(epoch, 
                                              self.model, 
                                              optimizer, 
                                              criterion, 
                                              self.config.l1_weight_decay)
            
            val_loss, val_acc = self.validate(epoch = epoch, 
                                     model = self.model, 
                                     criterion = criterion)

            train_stats["train_loss"].append(train_loss)
            train_stats["train_acc"].append(train_accuracy)

            val_stats["val_loss"].append(val_loss)
            val_stats["val_acc"].append(val_acc)


            
            # Log training and val loss in tensorboard
            # tensorboard.add_scalars("Loss", {"train_loss": train_loss, "val_loss": val_loss}, epoch)

            # Update learning rate
            scheduler.step(val_loss)


            # Save the model checkpoint
            model_ckpt(epoch, val_loss)

            # logger.info(f"Epoch: {epoch}| Train Loss: {train_loss} | Val_Loss: {val_loss}")

            # Earlystopping check
            early_stopping(val_loss)
            if early_stopping.early_stop:
                logger.info(f"Early Stopping Triggerd After {epoch} epoch")
                break
        return train_stats, val_stats



These are my parameters


weights: IMAGENET1K_V1
input_shape: [3, 224, 224] # c x h x w
freeze_all: False
freeze_till: 10
learning_rate: 0.0001
classes: 10
dropout_rate: 0.3
l2_weight_decay: 0.05  
l1_weight_decay: 0.000002  
lr_reduce_factor: 0.2
lr_reduce_patience: 10
min_lr: 0.000001
early_stopping_patience: 15
early_stopping_delta: 0.01  # Minimum improvement to be considered as an improvement
batch_size: 32
num_epochs: 10
optimizer: Adam
momentum: 0.9

Augmentations:

train_transforms:

Resize:

size: [224, 224]


ColorJitter:

brightness: 0.2
contrast: 0.2
saturation: 0.2
hue: 0.1


ToTensor: {}
RandomHorizontalFlip:

p: 0.5


RandomRotation:

degrees: 30




test_transforms:

Resize:

size: [224, 224]


RandomHorizontalFlip:

p: 0.5


ToTensor: {}



And this is my class weights:
{
    "A": 21.72651356993737,
    "B": 27.38684210526316,
    "C": 30.881305637982194,
    "D": 5.987917146144994,
    "E": 10.784455958549223,
    "F": 7.217059639389737,
    "G": 16.78548387096774,
    "H": 6.528858218318695,
    "I": 5.899659863945578,
    "J": 9.565257352941176
}

And this is my total number of images in each class.

{
    "A": 479,
    "B": 380,
    "C": 337,
    "D": 1738,
    "E": 965,
    "F": 1442,
    "G": 620,
    "H": 1594,
    "I": 1764,
    "J": 1088
}

Need your kind support to improve my model learning.

